# Gmail Blue Bar issue

Tags: gmail

When I first open gmail and it loads there is a long blue bar to the top left of the first email every time I first open it. Once I have clicked on an email and then going back to the Inbox the blue bar disappears. Has anyone heard of this problem or issue and have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Does pressing J or K move it up and down? It sounds like the keyboard shortcut conversation indicator. It is just showing you which conversation is currently selected by keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Yes. I pressed J and the blue bar went down

Comment: Then as I have said, this is the indicator for showing the conversation currently selected by gmail keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: You can't remove the blue line completely from gmail. If you want to remove it when you are composing an email, press CTRL+A to select all of the text and then press SHIFT+Left arrow in order to remove indentation and blue bar.

Comment: You won't believe this, but in trying everything you suggested, including your last one of just pressing cntrl a and shift left arrow, when i closed gmail and reopened it, the blue bar is now gone.  i have no idea how or why, it just is.

Comment: Check that.  It's back.  I knew it was too simple.  It only appears the FIRST time I load gmail.  Then when i open an email and go back to the inbox, the big blue line is gone.  Too wild.  No solution yet.

Comment: Glad it worked! I expect it'll be back at some point, but at least it is gone for now. :P

Edited to add: Oh, that was fast. As I said, you can't remove the blue bar completely from gmail... just remove it when composing messages.

Comment: By the way - I tried uninstalling gText which is the Mighty Text extention for gmail and then reinstalling it - no solution there either.

Comment: That's because the solution you want isn't possible without coding something yourself to remove it...

Comment: 1) Thanks again.  I have to keep saying that.  2) What caused this to suddenly happen out of the blue?  3) Why do I have to "code" something to stop this?  4) I don't even know how to "code" something lol.

Comment: It's been like this for a fair old time for me - I wasn't aware that others didn't have the line. As far as 3 + 4: Coding something would be writing some code and running it as a browser extension/using tampermonkey to remove the blue bar from your perspective. In simple terms, you would be breaking the part of the page which shows the blue line. I think this is probably not an option for you as you've stated you can't code, so I am afraid you're just going to have to live with the blue line.

Answer (score -2):

In Settings, try turning off Keyboard shortcuts.